# Type check in JSR-303 custom validator initialize method

Tags: bean-validation

I'm attempting to create a class level JSR-303 validation definition that checks that one property occurs before another in time. Because the this validation only makes sense for Calendar properties I was wondering if it is possible to test the property type in the initialize method.

My annotation definition is:

```
@Target({TYPE, ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = TemporalSequenceValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface TemporalSequence {

    String message() default "{uk.co.zodiac2000.vcms.constraints.TemporalSequence}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};    
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
    String first();
    String second();
}
```

and the validator implementation:

```
public class TemporalSequenceValidator implements 
    ConstraintValidator<TemporalSequence, Object> {
    private String firstFieldName;
    private String secondFieldName;

    @Override
    public void initialize(final TemporalSequence constraintAnnotation) {
        firstFieldName = constraintAnnotation.first();
        secondFieldName = constraintAnnotation.second();
        // Is it possible to test type of firstFieldName and
        // secondFieldName properties here?
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(final Object value, final ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        // omitted
    }
}
```

Is this a sensible thing to do? What approach would you suggest I use if it is? And what action should occur if the properties are not of the correct type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really do the check in `initialize()` since you can't access the validated object there. Instead you could check the type of the fields of the validated object in `isValid()` using reflection:

```
if ( !Calendar.class.isAssignableFrom( 
    value.getClass().getField( firstFieldName ).getType() ) ) {
    throw new ValidationException( "Field " + firstFieldName + " is not of type Calendar." );
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gunnar. Your answer has helped to point me in the right direction.